# When exactly are "dangling" post-up clauses executed?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

`post-up|down` clauses in `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian-based distributions can be either defined right after an interface definition, or "dangling". See a very simple example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.10.10
  ...
  post-up <command1>


post-up <command2>
```

It's pretty clear to me that `command1` will be executed once `eth0` is up. However, when is `command2` executed? Is it when *all* interfaces are up? Or is it when *any* interface is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command2` is not "dangling", it is a post-up option for eth0, so it will be executed right after `command1`. From [man interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html):

> Options are usually indented for clarity (as in the example above) but are not required to be.

Also, empty lines are ignored in `/etc/network/interfaces` (and in all included files).

Comment: I know the indentation is aesthetic; I didn't know the empty lines were ignored though. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Not sure this qualifies: https://sources.debian.org/src/ifupdown/0.8.35/config.c/#L406.